# Performance of many DOM elements vs. background repeat

Tags: javascript, css, performance, dom

I want to draw a timeline of "events" which happened in real time - the timeline consists of a "ruler" of vertical ticks, text time stamp for each round minute, and icons depicting the event type.

The issue I have is with the ruler. It should draw a "tall" vertical tick at round minute intervals. The interval between each round minute line is divided to 25 smaller intervals, each marked by a "short" tick. One in every 5 "short" ticks will be given a "medium" height.

Currently I do this by creating many span elements - 1 for each 25th of a minute. When a session is longer than 12 or I hide some of the spans using css (visibility:hidden) - the longer the session, the more items I hide. Regardless, this causes my DOM to contain a large number of span elements.

I thought about trying background-repeat to avoid the many span elements - but the question is will this actually make any difference in performance? What's the difference between drawing many DOM elements and repeating background images?

thanks

Comment: Is there a reason why you wouldn't want to use an SVG? Together with a library like D3 would make this much more manageable.

Comment: Background repeat is ___significantly___ faster than rendering hundreds / thousands of elements. It only has to calculate sizes _once_, then just repeat the render, instead of calculating the positioning of every single element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Background repeat is many time faster and performance diverges in favour of background repeat as you add elements.

Es:

10 element Vs Background repeat = background repeat 10x faster
100 element Vs Background repeat = background repeat 1000x faster
etc etc